# How to define that one of menu items is active by default?

Tags: html, css, menu

How to define that one of menu items is active by default?

```
    /* CSS */
        ul#menu a.active, ul#menu a:focus {
        outline-style: none;
        color: #AA0000;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
        }

    /* HTML */
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/hormenu_selector.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
<div  id = "menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>


    /* HORMENU_SELECTOR.JS */
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu ul li a').each(function() {
        var path = window.location.href;
        var current = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/'));
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        if (url == current) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        };
    });     
    });
```

Comment: What is the question here? Your code snippet already shows "Test1" being marked as default. Please be more specific.

Comment: It does not work if you check it. That's why I asked, ok?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos , did you try the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have something like this ,

```
<div id="Menu"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="/Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/Products.aspx">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="/AboutUs.aspx">About us</a></li>
<li><a href="/ContactUs.aspx">Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

For the active menu item to be selected , try to use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#Menu ul li a').each(function() {
    var path = window.location.href;
    var current = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/'));
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    if (url == current) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    };
});     

});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried it. So, I changed the following line in CSS: ul#menu a.active, ul#menu a:focus. Then I inserted your jQuery script right after </ul>. But nothing has changed.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos , try to add jquery script in a seperate file and then then link it.

Comment: Pliz check my Updated code. I posted CSS, HTML and JS. Still not working.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos try to use #menu li a instead of #menu ul li a

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I had a div with the id menu , but you are using that id for your ul

Comment: Changed to div id="menu" and tried both #menu li a and #menu ul li a. The same....Buff

Comment: @KlausosKlausos , you want that the menu which is clicked should have a different effect right?like Stackoverflow itself. Did i understand it properly.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos , update your question with a div which has the id=menu that will help.

Comment: Updated. Yes,I want the item Test1 look like if it would be active.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos , remove the class="active" from this line <li><a href="#" class="active">Test1</a></li>

Comment: @KlausosKlausos , the thing is it works based on the url of the page , it checks that the href and the url of the page should be same , you dont have any pages for your href that is why it is not working

Comment: There was my mistake in CSS,but the code posted here works. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You're using pseudo `:active` instead of class `active` in your CSS rule.

Try:

```
ul#menu a.active, ul#menu a:focus
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you can just change add "a.active" to the css definition:

```
ul#menu li a.active, ul#menu li a:focus {
    outline-style: none;
    color: #AA0000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

That way due to the class it is initially active.
you could also remove the a:active and use jquery like this:

```
$("ul#menu li a").click(function() { $(this).addClass("active") });
```

Comment: I checked it as well. Nothing changed.